# How to put vertical line among the words?

Tags: line, vertical

I want to put a vertical line among some words in order to separate them, for example I want this:

Website | Email | Address

But I cannot produce these vertical line perfectly. What should I do? (I do not want to use tabular environment)

Comment: You can use `$\vert$`, `$\mid$`, or `$|$`.  If you are using `T1` encoding, you can use `|` directly, but I don't recommend it, because if you change the font encoding back to `OT1`, it will come out wrong.

Comment: What's wrong with `|`?

Comment: If you need something wider/longer, you could use `\kern1pt\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{.6pt}{\baselineskip}\kern1pt` set up as a macro.

Comment: Thank you guys, the problem with '|' was about making horizontal line in the pdf file

Comment: As I note in my answer, the horizontal line (aka em dash) occurs when you are using the default `OT1` font encoding and use a `|` in non-math mode.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note that `|` does not work with default `OT1` font encoding (it comes out as an em dash).    Comment out my `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, recompile, and see.

The most versatile would be `\mybar`, which you define as a `\rule` of specified dimensions in the preamble.

The math versions include `\vert`, `|`, and `\mid`.

Lastly, variants can be applied to `\vert` and `|` in the form of `\big`, `\bigg`, `\Big`, and `\Bigg`; however, this will mess up line spacing when used inline.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand\mybar{\kern1pt\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{.8pt}{\baselineskip}\kern1pt}
\begin{document}
Website%
$\vert$Email%
$\mid$Email%
$|$Email%
\mybar Email%
|Email
\end{document}
```

[image]

For comparison, here is using a few "big" variants, as well as `OT1` encoding.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand\mybar{\kern1pt\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{\baselineskip}\kern1pt}
\begin{document}
Website%
$\bigg\vert$Email%
$\mid$Email%
$\Big|$Email%
\mybar Email%
|Email
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have the vertical bar always at the same place? I use your solution, but if there is a "wider" number like for example "100" is wider than "1", the vertical bar moves to the left or the right next to the number. Can I set a permanent width to either of the sides of the of the bar

Comment: @Bolle My guess is that this issue is that you have a stray space unaccounted for in your input, rather than an issue with `\mybar`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a question to the provided solution:

```
\newcommand\mybar{\kern1pt\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{\baselineskip}\kern1pt}
```

How can I colorize the bar? I tried this, below it doesn't work.

```
\newcommand\mybar[1]{
\color{#1}\kern1pt\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\leftbarwidth}{\baselineskip}\color{black}\kern3pt
}
```

call with:

```
\mybar[red] Foo
\mybar[green] Bar
```

Comment: This is a question, not an answer.

Comment: With an optional parameter, you need to provide a default value. Note also the presence of `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` to keep the color changes local: `\newcommand\mybar[1][black]{\begingroup\color{#1}\kern1pt\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{\baselineskip}\kern1pt\endgroup}`

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/253927)