# Formatting headers with LaTeX

Tags: header-footer

I came across a [document](https://www.bio.uni-jena.de/biophamedia/guideline-msc.pdf) on the Internet and found the headers used in this document are very appealing to me. How to make a **header** with the format: `<chpater-name> | <page-number>` and similar colors/fonts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion for a **KOMA-Script class** using package `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```latex
\documentclass[headings=optiontoheadandtoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[letterspace=200]{microtype}% https://www.ctan.org/pkg/microtype

\usepackage[automark,markcase=upper]{scrlayer-scrpage}% 
\clearpairofpagestyles
\lehead*{\pagemark\mypagenumberbar\leftmark}
\rohead*{\leftmark\mypagenumberbar\pagemark}

\renewcommand{\chaptermarkformat}{}% no chapter number in page header
\newcommand\mypagenumberbar{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{\enskip\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{\baselineskip}\enskip}}}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\color{gray}\sffamily\textls}% font settings for page header and footer
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalcolor}% normal color for page numbers

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter[head=General]{General Suggestions}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter[head=Delivery]{Delivery of the Thesis}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Cover Sheet}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Additional remarks:

Class option `headings=optiontoheadandtoc` activates the extended interpretation of the optional argument of sectioning commands. Eg. `\chapter[head=General]{General Suggestions}` puts »General« in the running head, but »General Suggestions« in ToC.

The starred versions of `\lehead` and `\rohead` uses the mandantory argument for both page styles `scrheadings` and `plain` (alias of `plain.scrheadings`). Therefore you get the header on chapter pages, too.

---

It is also possible to use package `scrlayer-scrpage` together with a **standard class**:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[letterspace=200]{microtype}% https://www.ctan.org/pkg/microtype

\usepackage[markcase=upper]{scrlayer-scrpage}% 
\clearpairofpagestyles
\lehead*{\pagemark\mypagenumberbar\leftmark}
\rohead*{\leftmark\mypagenumberbar\pagemark}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeMarkcase{#1}}{}}% no chapter number in page header
\newcommand\mypagenumberbar{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{\enskip\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{\baselineskip}\enskip}}}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\color{gray}\sffamily\textls}% font settings for page header and footer
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalcolor}% normal color for page numbers

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{General Suggestions}\chaptermark{General}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Delivery of the Thesis}\chaptermark{Delivery}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Cover Sheet}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have the vertical bar always at the same place? I use your solution, but if there is a "wider" number like for example "100" is wider than "1", the vertical bar moves to the left or the right next to the the pagenumber

Comment: @Bolle Yes, it is possible: put `\pagemark` in a box of a fixed width. Therefore you could replace `\pagemark` in `\lehead*` and `\rohead*` by `\makebox[\widthof{999}][r]{\pagemark}`.  `\widthof{999}` needs package `calc` and defines the width of the box. `r` declares the alignment of the page number in the box. `r` can be replaced by `l` or the default `c`.

Answer (score 1):

This is from the linked document you provided:

[image: Linked picture]

This is what the code I am providing produces:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[letterspace=200]{microtype} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62351/245306

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/400110/245306
\newcommand\mybar{\kern1pt\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{.8pt}{\baselineskip}\kern1pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} % Changed this to include chapter name only

\fancyhead[R]{{\color{gray} \sffamily \textls{\MakeUppercase\leftmark}} \textbf{\mybar\ \thepage}}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}      % Removes head rule

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Methodology}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

The code is quite ugly but does as you require, the referenced TEX.SE answers for `microtype` and the custom command `\mybar` were adopted herein and if you want to customise them further, they are explained in more detail in the answers. Hope this helps, if you need anything further then comment and I'll try to explain more.

Edit: Deleted then edited the code and image as I was using `\chaptername` by mistake and not `\leftmark` after customising it.

Comment: Would it possible to do it using the package `scrlayer-scrpage` instead of `fancyhdr`? I am using the document class `scrbook` and LaTeX warned me that it is not recommended to use `fancyhdr` and `scrbook` together.

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend that you open a new question and link to this question. Put the code I put here in your question with the image of how it looks and ask how to implement this header in the `scrbook` class as I have no experience with it!